# external hdd does not get detected in front usb port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I Have a External HDD with two **Usb cables** .
One usb cable is mini usb type and the other one is a standard usb cable.
THE mini usb cable originally came with the toshibha externall hdd.My hdd is toshibha

Model   Canvio

MPN      593400A

Type    Desktop External HDD

Product Line    Canvio

Storage Capacity     500GB

My motherboard is INTEL DH61H0.Tt has 4 back usb 2.0 ports.

**The problem is when I attach the hdd with my new usb cable on FRONT port it does not get recognized and it gives a beep beep sound but attaching with the old original mini USB cable it gets recognized**

IN the back port with both the cables the external hdd gets recognized.
I also checked the voltage of the fron port with multimeter .  it  gave 5.12v.

MY father is a technician in electrical field .He desoldered the front front port full IC panel and bought a new one from the market.

BUT after attaching the NEW FRONT PORT PANEL the result was same.

**WITH THE NEW CABLE HDD IS NOT RECOGNIZING AT THE FRONT BUT AT the back port it is recognzing**

MY new usb cable looks like this (https://www.amazon.in/AmazonBasics-Charging-Android-Phones-Connectors/dp/B0711PVX6Z?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=_k_CjwKCAjw-4_mBRBuEiwA5xnFIESiROHSBS15aYMb-cogG0L6CrvhMIZCYbtuisDYiUk_OS1x4E_JEBoCd7AQAvD_BwE_k_&gclid=CjwKCAjw-4_mBRBuEiwA5xnFIESiROHSBS15aYMb-cogG0L6CrvhMIZCYbtuisDYiUk_OS1x4E_JEBoCd7AQAvD_BwE)

WHAT IS THE PROBLEMN WITH THE FRONT PORTS OR WITH THE **NEW CABLE**?

Comment: What are your exact disk, cable and port specifications front and back? Evidently there is a difference.

Comment: If you can lay your hands on another cable, that will answer where the fault lies.

Comment: @harrymc The full front port that i bought is similar to this [LINK](https://www.amazon.in/Computer-Front-Panel-Audio-Earphone/dp/B00B2ZAPHA)  ,the back ports are attached with INTELdh61Ho(USB 2.0 ports ),the cable is a random USB cable bought from the market., **what DISK are u talking about**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with front ports is that there is additional cable between the mainboard and front receptacles, while the back USB connectors are residing on a solid power (and signal) platform. The extra cable adds at least one extra connector (for USB 2.0 this is a vanilla 2x5 IDC 0.1" junk), and extra power wires of unknown quality. Either you have an additional voltage drop on front ports (which should be measured at full load, not on empty port) due to this extra cable, or the internal cable quality (and its internal connector) is bad and cripple USB signals. Or just too many extra interconnects introduces too much of USB signal deterioration, and your particular HDD is too (marginally) sensitive to signal quality.

ADDITION: If your cable looks like this one,

[image]

there is absolutely no chance that this cable will work at USB HS mode (480 Mbps) with any reliability. The USB cable must be shielded.

ADDITION2: the [CANVIO 593400A device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pS_EDsP2KI) uses SATA drive that needs 1.0A to operate, and likely quite more (probably 1.5 - 1.8 A peak) when it spins up. Which would severely exceed port capability, especially over the skinny internal extra cable. This combination is clearly marginal and no wonder that it fails to work after slight change in component/cable quality.

[image]

ADDITION3: The cable shown above cannot supply data for both ports, it has only one pair of green-white wires. So only one port can possibly work, but with very low reliability due to improper cable construction. It might work OK for mice or keyboards only. To work more or less better with HS (480 Mbps) drives, your internal cable should look like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K82WQ7K)

[image]

Comment: what additional cable are u talking about?is it the two cables named **audio and usb** ? I can give the pic of the front port ic panel that i bought from the market but i dont have enough reputations to upload it. I have measured the front port using multimeter while pc on .

Comment: @SaumyojitDas, I thought I was clear, it is the cable that connects mainboard with front receptacles. The VBUS voltage should be measured UNDER LOAD, which means at least 5-10 Ohms.

Comment: there are two cables with the this ic panel [link](https://www.amazon.in/SuperCart-Computer-Front-Panel-Earphone/dp/B07H32QLHS?tag=googinhydr18418-21) one audio which sits on **faudio** pin  and one usb which sits on **F usb** on the motherboard (DH61HO).  what is  cable that connects mainboard with front receptacles.?give me a link or something so that i can understand by seeing a pic or video.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas, it should be obvious that the audio part of the internal cable has nothing to do with USB. Why do you keep bringing the audio cable? After seeing your link, your problem is that this kind of cable construction (flat ribbon) is **absolutely inadequate** for USB 2.0 HS traffic. Get a shielded cable.

Comment: give me a link of a shielded cable. how it looks like.Another thing is that when i **join the external hdd using the original usb cable on this front port it gets detected**.How is  that possible? **this kind of cable construction (flat ribbon)** this type of front port was there in my pc from the beginning until it got damaged due to wear and tear last 3 weeks back so i had to buy a new one which is in the picture u gave.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas, I don't know how it is possible at all to work with the pictured cable harness. To start, the panel has 2 USB ports, while the USB connector has only one set of green-white wires. If anything, everything is possible - different PCB, different wire size, different solder job.

Comment: My Hdd model is this [link](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822149118) . The **original cable** 's  end that goes in my drive is a mini USB which is working fine with the front ports and back ports.

Comment: no solution so far . The original cable is a mini usb 2.0 which works fine on one front port but does not work on the second front port . **The new usb cable** does not work on both the front ports. Will i buy a new mini usb cable from toshibha or what??

Comment: the cable that u recently added Uxcell a13121900ux0279 Expansion 2 Ports  is it for the front panel or the rear panel? One consumer  in the given link named Antonio F. says "( The cables are NOT long, so if you need to reach the inner edge of the motherboard (toward the front of computer case) more than likely will NOT reach)"  thats why i am little bit confused . My pc case is [link](https://www.flipkart.com/iball-i8190-full-tower-cabinet/p/itmd6f95t7hhhssn) .  **Also i came across a you tube video recently [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmmWs57JDpA)**  must check it

Comment: latest update: Last day i asked a question (will it be fitted on the front panel or not) in the Customer questions & answers of [link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00K82WQ7K?ref_=pe_623860_70668520_dpLink)   one consumer named red lodger replied that   **Not without modification. It is designed to fit into the rear card slot openings. Also, as I recall the cable is fairly short so it most likely would only reach the lowest available front panel slot after modification of the plastic slot cover.**

Comment: still waiting for u sir to reply.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas, what to reply? You asked why some cables/ports work and some don't. I explained that the front cable is completely out of USB specs and can't possibly meet signal integrity requirements. I provided a picture of how the cable SHOULD LOOK LIKE, SIMILAR.The more-or less acceptable cables must be shielded and typically have a round shape. Whether it fits or unfits mechanically, short or long, is not my problem, find a longer one.

Comment: can u just tell me what does the video meant here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmmWs57JDpA) . The person in the video suffers from the same problemn of not detecting usb front port.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas, this video has nothing to do with your case. It is about USB3, while you have wrong cable for USB2.

Comment: i was searching some videos on this topic on u tube .can u just see this two videos whether any of the one method will work or not?[LINUS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0fdv6YdYqQ)   and [FRONT PANEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqpAKg0ffhY)

Answer (score 1):

If the cable is the one that you linked to (amazon one) it is only for power not for data.

If you are on a linux based system you can run `lsusb` to look at usb devices.
If you are on a windows system take a look at the device manager by right clicking `my computer` and clicking `manage` look under unrecognized or USB.

The technical product specs says your motherboard has eight USB 2.0 ports.
I would double check the orientation/state of the plug from the front panel to the motherboard. Sometimes the plug does not come with the standard plastic filler on the plug which will prevent it from being plugged in upside down.

Comment: I am using windows 10 . The Amazon linked cable is the not the cable that I bought . My new cable looks like it . With the new cable I can data transfer easily when connected to **back port** but on front port it doesn't get recognized and I get a beep beep sound.

Comment: From product link: "Supports up to 480 mbps data transmission speed".  So it isn't a power-only cable.

Comment: The Amazon linked cable I didn't buy it.my new cable looks similar like it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved partially.I bought a new USB cable from  adata company and HDD gets noticed in one usb port but in the other it doesn't work.
I still don't have any idea what is the cause of this problem